# Passing Drop Down Menu Value to CSV

Tags: php, html, csv, if-statement

I've got a form that has three drop down menus.  In the html the options are named 0, 1 and 2 for validation purposes, and the actual inline text are the different options.

When I push the values to .csv, instead of having it just push the number, I wrote a few `if statements` to rename the variable that was saved.  I've got it working, but rather than just have a bunch of `if statements` hanging around I thought I would slip them into a function and just call the function.  However, when I do that, the value of whatever option the user selected reverts back to being stored as 0, 1 or 2 in the .csv file.

My question is what is my function missing that is causing it to only pick the numbered value?

**HTML:**

```
<select id="semesterSelector" name="semesterSelector" onchange="checkPage5()">
<option value="0">Select</option>
<option value="1">Fall</option>
<option value="2">Spring</option>
</select>
```

**PHP:**

```
$semesterSelector = $_POST["semesterSelector"];

function semesterNameChange(){
if($semesterSelector == 1)
    {
        $semesterSelector = "Fall";
    }
    elseif($semesterSelector == 2)
        {
            $semesterSelector = "Spring";
        }
}
semesterNameChange();
```

**Pushing the Value to Csv:**

```
$csvData = [...] $semesterSelector [...]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PHP, functions have their own scope. This basically means, that if you're trying to access variables from outside the function, you would either need to pass them in (In between the parenthesis), or you would need to use `global` to allow outside variables to be used within the scope of your function. In this case, you need to simply add `global $semesterSelector` at the top of your function.

```
function semesterNameChange(){
    global $semesterSelector;
    if($semesterSelector == 1)
    {
        $semesterSelector = "Fall";
    }
    elseif($semesterSelector == 2)
    {
        $semesterSelector = "Spring";
    }
}
semesterNameChange();
```

Another way could be to pass the value directly into the function:

```
function semesterNameChange($selectValue) {
    if( $selectValue == 1 )
    {
        return "Fall";
    }
    elseif ( $selectValue == 2 )
    {
        return "Spring";
    }
}

$semesterSelector = semesterNameChange($_POST["semesterSelector"]);
```

Comment: You, sir, are my hero today :)

Answer (score 0):

Can you be sure that your `<form>` tag has method="POST"?  Also saying == 1 in loosely typed language can get you into trouble.  Let's be sure we have an integer and strictly evaluate it:

```
$semesterSelector = (integer) $_POST["semesterSelector"];

function semesterNameChange(){
    global $semesterSelector;
    if ($semesterSelector === 1)
```